# VS Code Autocorrect

Tags: visual-studio-code, spell-checking, autocorrect, spelling

I'm looking for a way to automatically replace my commonly misspelt words in VS Code.

Is there something out there / how would I create something where I can add a particular string to find, string to replace with and a syntax/filetypes for the autocorrect to be active in?

Example:

backgorund | background | css/scss/less

To clarify, I want it to be automatically corrected, no key inputs.

Answer (score 5):

There is an [Auto Correct](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sygene.auto-correct) extension for VS Code.

Its configuration is pretty straightforward. In your case just add the following to your `settings.json`

```
"auto-correct.dictionary": [
{
  "languages": ["javascript","css","html"],
  "words": {
    "backgorund": "background"
  }
}]
```

And "backgorund" will be automatically corrected without specific key presses.

Comment: this extension *only* works with a specific key presses https://github.com/genesy/auto-correct/issues/11 - I would like `.` to be my key, but it currently does not work this way

Answer (score 0):

Try [Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker), it has more functions than Auto-correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Grammarly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=znck.grammarly) for VS Code (it also allows to login with premium account)